# Secret username and password on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am having troubles to manage secret password on Jenkins. I want that the password is not showed on the log but i tried in two ways without success:

**First attempt**

I tried setting up with user and pwd with Global credentials (unrestricted) like this :

[image]

and i executed :

```
docker run -u root -v $(pwd)/:/usr/src/app deploy npm run application -- --params.login.user=$USER --params.login.password=$PWD
```

but i can see in the log that the user is wrote correctly but the pwd is being written like its path:

```
e2e@2.2.1 e2: `protractor dist/out-tsc/e2e/cucumberconfig.js "--params.login.user=user" "--**params.login.password=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/application/app/e2e_test**"
```

And in my automatic test is also by entering the full path instead of the value of the variable.

**Second attempt**

I tried using a secret text like this:

[image]

```
 docker run -u root -v $(pwd)/:/usr/src/app deploy npm run application -- --params.login.user=$USER --params.login.password=$PASS
```

But on the console log is being displayed the password as it is.

Someone can help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> But on the console log is being displayed the password as it is.

is it mean in clear text?

If so - use mask password plugin to solve the issue.

Comment: I know that it works but i dont want to install anything, i used :set +x  at the beginning and set -x at the end and it is worked

Answer (score 0):

i used :
set +x
docker run -u root -v $(pwd)/:/usr/src/app deploy npm run application -- -params.login.user=$USER --params.login.password=$PWD
set -x

and that worked.